# Extract sAMAccountName of a User inside a Security Group

Tags: python, active-directory

I know that I can do this by querying AD again inside the loop, but that will generate a significant number of calls that I'm hoping to avoid. Here's my code:

```
import os, sys
import re
import datetime
import getpass
import ldap

debug = True
now = datetime.datetime.now()

print '******************\n##########\n******************\n'

l = ldap.initialize("ldap://##########")

if debug:
    l.simple_bind_s("ADuser@##########","##########")
else:
    try:
        username = raw_input('Username: ')
        password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
        l.simple_bind_s(username + '@##########', password)
    except ldap.LDAPError, e:
        print e
        raw_input('Press any key to continue')
        sys.exit()

baseDN = "OU=##########, OU=##########, OU=##########, DC=##########, DC=##########"
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE

retrieveAttributes = None
searchFilter = "CN=*"

try:
    ldap_result_id = l.search(baseDN, searchScope, searchFilter, retrieveAttributes)
    result_set = []
    while 1:
        result_type, result_data = l.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
        if (result_data == []):
            break
        else:
            if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
                result_set.append(result_data)
    try:
        f = open(os.environ['userprofile'] + '\\Desktop\\' + now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '_Report.csv', 'w')
        f.write('Full Name, Shared Account Name, Shared Account Code\n')
        try:
            for i in range(len(result_set)):
                for entry in result_set[i]:
                    #print entry[1]['cn'][0] #Security Group name
                    try:
                        if entry[1]['member']:
                            for member in entry[1]['member']: #Group members
                                m = re.search('CN=(.+?),OU', member).group(1)

                                account = entry[1]['cn'][0]
                                description = entry[1]['description'][0].rstrip('\n')
                                member = m.replace('\\', '')

                                f.write('"' + member + '", ' + description + ', ' + account + '\n')
                    except:
                        pass
        finally:
            f.close()
    except IOError, e:
        print e
    l.unbind_s()
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
    print e
    raw_input('Press any key to continue')
```

How can I pull the list of Security Groups, Members, and *then* also grab the individual user's sAMAccountName as well? Or is it just not possible without another lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the LDAP protocol there is no ability to perform the action you are asking.

You of course, could simplify the code layout by making a method call to obtain sAMAccountName from the DN you find listed in the group.

These kind of actions are typical within LDAP but they happen very fast.

Comment: So you think even with a few thousand users that this isn't overkill?